# Write progress from a long running process

Tags: logging, monitoring

We have some long running processes which could run for as long as an hour up to 6 hours.

Some of the processes are started by hand and the user wants to see what the progress of the process is.

Without getting into to much details of the actual details, you could think of:

- Fetching data
- Update client info
- remove false data
- create external  files
- create pdf

This process of course consists of loads of different classes, and sometimes I want those individual classes to write progress.

For example: When I am only interested in high overview progress, I could write the progress from the top level facade, but I also want to write progress in the service which creates the pdf's, so that class and it's subclasses also have to write progress.

My question is: how can I write progress from all those classes regarding the same 'base' process without passing some kind of processid from class to class?

What I thought of is creating a loggingservice class which takes care of the logging and passing that from class to class, but that seems so nasty to hand every single class the logging service.

Second I thought of is to create a static loggingservice class for the logging (which I find common in applications for the normal error logging) but then I still have to pass the processId around

Third I thought of creating a factory to be called from every class, but then I still have to pass the processId around

Fourth I thought of injecting the loggingservice class in every class, but then I still have to pass the processId around and it seems like a wrong kind of dependency for a class to have, a dependency for a logger.

So I am looking for either number 5, or reasons why 1,2,3 or 4 is a good idea anyway and the downsides I see are not relevant or important.

Comment: It is operating system specific. You might consider [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) on Linux or POSIX.

Comment: I don't think it's realy platform specific. I've got 2 problems at hand: change my business code for adding logging, and how to add the knowledge of the running process to the business code. I don't think this is something I would do different on other platforms....

Comment: The low level logging machinery is OS specific.

Comment: What OS, what programming language, what code size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do this by letting every long-running class implement an interface, e.g. `LongRunning`, with a single method `reportProgress()`. Your logging service would simply be notified of the existence of such long runners, periodically query their status, and then report on the general state of the world in whatever way it sees fit.

Your business code still has to be interleaved with logging statements that way, but otherwise your existing classes don't have to adapt to anything external, and that's the most important thing in my view: not changing business code that already does its job for extraneous reasons.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the business code DOES change like I should add the logging code in my business code? That what I think you are saying because you say `Your business code still has to be interleaved with logging statements that way` but I got confused because you also say `the most important thing in my view: not changing business code that already does its job for extraneous reasons`

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Every principle has a point of diminishing returns, and I think inserting a line of logging into an inner loop somewhere is usually not *too* bad to make something progress-aware. You could use AOP to reduce this to 0 lines, but that's usually like cracking a peanut with a sledgehammer (or a hydraulic press).

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that all of these solutions *dirty* your code with logging / reporting code that breaks separation of concerns. This sort of problem is exactly why **Aspect Oriented Programming** exists:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (emphasis mine):

> Aspect-oriented programming entails breaking down program logic into distinct parts (so-called concerns, cohesive areas of functionality). Nearly all programming paradigms support some level of grouping and encapsulation of concerns into separate, independent entities by providing abstractions (e.g., functions, procedures, modules, classes, methods) that can be used for implementing, abstracting and composing these concerns. **Some concerns "cut across" multiple abstractions in a program, and defy these forms of implementation. These concerns are called cross-cutting concerns.**

Also relevant: [Cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)

Essentially, you want something that can touch upon all aspects of your application in a particular scenario. In your case, such logging is a cross-cutting concern.

I can't help you with any implementation details as your question doesn't mention a language or a platform. But many languages offer Aspect Oriented Programming natively, or there are frameworks that assist with this process.

Examples:

- Java: [Guice AOP](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP)
- Python: [Pytilities](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytilities/)
- Ruby: [Aquarium](http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/)
- PHP: [Go!](http://go.aopphp.com/)

Comment: I've heard logging as a cross cutting concern, like log every method start and every method end. But is this kind of logging also a cross cutting concern, when it's not the same for every method?

Comment: Yes it is, but to elaborate further starts to get into implementation details.

Comment: @Michel: AOP frameworks will give you some control about which methods to log, and how. Furthermore, if you want to log something which does not map to a function call, you might consider to refactor your code and extract a method with the granularity you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of logging (i.e. your application telling some logging system, perhaps using  [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) on Linux, what is going on) you might think of it differently: your application could be a *server* for *requests* querying its state.

Then you might even make your app some [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) server (and you'll have also to code the tiny command-line client to query it).

You could also have your app becoming a specialized web server (e.g. using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), etc... see [this list](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18091/1877)) and be queriable thru usual browser technologies.

These days, for an application which can run an entire working day, I would enable some web server technologies inside it. Even a cheap printer is today able to give its status thru some web interface.

Your internal classes might give their state e.g. by updating some "global" variables or application wide data, etc... (Of course use mutexes for synchronization issues).

The aspect-oriented perspective from [durron597's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/277117/40065) is still relevant. If your application is a big C or C++ code compiled by GCC, you might consider using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to customize the compiler for such (aspect-oriented) purposes. But that would be compiler specific, would take a week of effort, etc.

BTW, I am not sure that an externally queriable state should be fine-grained. I believe that updating that state every dozen of seconds is enough (I'm not thinking of periodical upgrade, but of coarse-grained state). Then you probably don't have to touch a big lot of code. YMMV.

Whatever you do, you have to design it quite early. The wikipages on [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) might be relevant.

Comment: interesting thought. But that doesn't change much of the fact that my deep nested classes need to 'report' the info?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but anyways ... to address the concerns of 'dirtying' code in the accepted answer, consider the visitor pattern.

Update reportProgress() method to take a visitor param which contains the code specific to reporting for each concrete instance, then the concrete instance calls the appropriate visitor method.

This way you can keep your business logic code separate from your logging / reporting code. You'd also be able to provide different logging implementations as different visitors.